# No puedo listar datos de manera ordenada

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En esta parte quise ordenar los datos entradas, me pidieron de que si el título ingresado era mayor que 21 tendría que finalizar en puntos suspensivos, para que encaje con los otros cortos,y los cortos quedarían normal, pero al momento de ejecutar me sale al revés. No sé en qué parte pude haber fallado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
A donde señala la flecha tenía que haberme salido, la parte que se encontraba encima del 1.

Comment: Tu lenguaje no es Netbeans, sino Java. El IDE nada tiene que ver con la pregunta. Además, tanto el código como los mensajes de error deben ir _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta agregar los puntos sustantivos al propio valor del String, algo asi:

```
public static String formato(String titulo){
  String tituloConformado;
    if (titulo.length() >= 21) {
        tituloConformado = titulo.substring(0, 21) + "..";
        System.out.println(tituloConformado);
    } else {
        tituloConformado = titulo;
        System.out.println(tituloConformado);
    }

    return tituloConformado;
```

No deberias tener ningun problema asi, espero sea la solucion a tu problema.